# Python: Permission denied when writing to file

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I am writing a script on my Windows VM to "compile" my Python scripts as a .exe file.  I followed several tutorials online to no prevail.  Some help from the community would be great!

Location of files: C:\Users\NAME\Desktop
Python Install Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python

hello.py

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

compiler.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe # has been installed
import os

filename = raw_input("File to compile: ")
setup(console=[filename])
```

When I run the script in CMD using the command "python compiler.py install", I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\NAME\Desktop>python compiler.py install
File to compile: hello.py
running install
running build
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Lib\site-packages\UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info: Permission denied
C:\Users\NAME\Desktop>
```

I have no clue why I am receiving this error, as Python should have permission to read and write files in its installation folder.  Thanks for any advice!

EDIT:  I am running 2.7, I am not sure whether it matters.  But just in case it does!

Comment: Clearly you're doing this on the command prompt (`cmd`). So try running `cmd` as administrator and see if that gets you around the permission issues

Comment: @inspectorG4dget That worked!  I just need to find where the file was saved to... I will change the CWD so it should save to where the compiler file is. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely, the file was saved to `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\…`. Though, it is also possible that it was saved in `C:\Python27\…` (or wherever your python installation lives)

Comment: hello.py -> hello.exe. Sounds about right (I stopped using windows a while back, so my memory is a little fuzzy)

Comment: I still haven't found the file... I have searched my whole computer for files ending in .exe and that were modified today. :/

Comment: No errors have been returned, so I assume it has.  The tutorial I have used was: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: As I ran it as Administrator, I also searched C:\Windows\System 32.

Comment: Post the command line output of running `python setup.py py2exe`

Comment: Are you sure you want to look at it? XD

Comment: It is over 15k characters... brb I will upload it to my site

Comment: Not really, but I can't help without looking at it. And even if I can't, it'll help someone else help you

Comment: Here is the link: (I may delete it in a day or so) http://testing.nullsoftware.net/cmd_output.txt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18082/discussion-between-inspectorg4dget-and-patrick-murray)

Answer (score 1):

> *Python should have permission to read and write files in its installation folder*

That's not actually true. Permissions are resolved on Windows not by the program that is running, but the *user account* which is doing the action. So the answer is that *your user account* does not have access to write to the Python installation folder.

In general, to install system-wide software (which you're trying to do), you would need to run your commands under a local administrator account. However, a better option might be to find a way to install your program somewhere else (for testing purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with the permissions, it's because you're running the wrong command.

you typed in: C:\Users\NAME\Desktop>python compiler.py install

which SHOULD BE:

C:\Users\NAME\Desktop>python compiler.py py2exe

:-)